# Can Perforce do a sort of changelist white list?

Tags: locking, perforce, whitelist

Is it possible to restrict write access to a Perforce depot, but still allowing particular changelists? Basically, instead of spending lots of time managing users in a write-enabled group during a code lock (add user, wait for check-in, remove user) I'd rather just have a list I add approved changelist numbers to.

Comment: Seems like it would be just as quick to take a user in or out of a group as it is to edit your list of CLs.  I'm 99% sure Perforce can't do this anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a trigger script to do it. I do the same thing using JIRA. When someone types in a comment, they include the Jira number. My trigger queries the Jira, and makes sure there is the appropriate comment in the Jira before allowing them to submit.

You can't really do it on changelists since you don't know the changelist number until the actual submit happens.